# Getting java null pointer exception on cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

mcrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    preview.buildDrawingCache();
    bitmap=preview.getDrawingCache();
    CropImage.activity(uri)
            .start(Previewimage.this);
    cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Bitmap cropped = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
    preview.setImageBitmap(cropped);
```

}
};

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView.getCroppedImage()' on a null object reference

Comment: Where do you initialize your `cropImageView ` ?

Comment: check if your bitmap is null or not and intialize your cropImageView propery by declaring it as global as try again

Comment: Try to set your bitMap in the onCreate function

Comment: Thanks !! got it I am using third party libraries where i need to initialize with third party library i initialize with my ownapp

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `bitmap` is null: check `preview`is not null and `preview.getDrawingCache();` doesn't return a null value.